# Retornar Imagem (Blob do Banco de dados)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Não estou conseguindo retornar as imagens de um controller. Abaixo explico todos a codificação:

Eu criei um controller, e uma view para esse controller que retorna a imagem que está em um campo blob do Oracle. Ela funcionou, normalmente com o controller e view abaixo:

```
 public class ImagemController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Imagem
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult GetImagem(int id)
        {
            Entities1 tabela = new Entities1();

            byte[] BlobImg = tabela.DATABINARY.Where(p => p.ID.Equals(843)).Select(p => p.DATA).FirstOrDefault();
            return File(BlobImg, "image/png");
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Teste de Imagem</h2>

<img src="@Url.Action("GetImagem")" width="100"/>
```

Agora, criei um novo controller, para buscar informações de estoque e neste controller eu tenho o atributo IDBLOB, conforme abaixo:

```
 public class ProntaEntregaController : Controller
    {
        // GET: ProntaEntrega

      public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Entities1 Estoque = new Entities1();

            List<V500_ESTOQUE_PE_WEB> ProntaE = (from p in Estoque.V500_ESTOQUE_PE_WEB select p).Where(x => x.IDBLOB != null).ToList();

            return View(ProntaE);
        }
    }
}
```

E fiz a view, conforme abaixo só pra teste, porém, as imagens não são retornadas. Fica apenas um ícone de imagem, como se ela não carregasse (vou colocar só uma parte pra não ficar muito longo):

```
 <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(d => item.COD_REDUZIDO)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(d => item.TOTAL_KG_PE)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", new { id = item.IDBLOB })" width=100 />
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: você lembrou de substituir o id fixo pelo parâmetro da sua controller, né? Na Action `GetImagem(int id)` ...
... `Where(p => p.ID.Equals(843))`

Comment: Sim. Coloquei fixo só pra testar, mas mesmo assim a imagem não vem